# How to loop with case esac in shell scripting?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'd like to write a script where if a user enters a path which contains his/her `$HOME` directory, it would raise an error and the script will run until user enters a valid path in which the loop will break.

Apparently it gives a syntax error if I have `continue` or `break` commands. What do I do wrong here? Thanks, Jen.

```
#!/bin/bash

function project1_install_dir_path() {   

    boolian_2=true; 
    while true; do

    if [ "$boolian_2" = true ] ; then

       read -p "Enter FULL folder path where you want to install colsim1:" fullpath

       echo "you have enterd "$fullpath". Please press 'y' to confirm and 'n' to enter again"

       case "$fullpath" in

       "$HOME"*) echo "Error: The path cannot be in your HOME" ;; continue      
       */home*) echo "Error: The path cannot contain 'home' in the path" ;; continue
       *) echo "you have entered a valid path" ;; break

       esac
       done    
   fi    
}

function main() {

project1_install_dir_path    
}
```

**Terminal Output**

```
jen@ss23:/bash_file.sh 
-bash: /project/bash_file.sh: line 62: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: /project/bash_file.sh: line 62: ` "$HOME"*) echo "Error: The path cannot be in your HOME" ;; continue
```

Comment: The `;;` at the end of the case mark the end. Thus, your following `break` or `continue` commands are ignored. `*) echo "you have entered a valid path" ; break ;;` is more like what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You should really check your indentation. The final `done` and `fi` statements are in the wrong order although your indentation suggests otherwise. Another issue is the `case` statement. The basic syntax is

```
case $SOMETHING in
    value1)
        statement1;
        statement2;
        ;;
    value2)
        statement3;
        statement4;
        ;;
esac
```

That is: the final `;;` must actually be the last statement for each *case* and indicates its end. If you want to `continue` in some case, then you need to put that `continue` statement *before* any `;;`, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

function project1_install_dir_path() {   

    boolian_2=true; 
    while true; do
        if [ "$boolian_2" = true ] ; then
            read -p "Enter FULL folder path where you want to install colsim1:" fullpath
            echo "you have enterd '$fullpath'. Please press 'y' to confirm and 'n' to enter again"
            case "$fullpath" in
                "$HOME"*) 
                    echo "Error: The path cannot be in your HOME"; 
                    continue;
                    ;;
                */home*)
                    echo "Error: The path cannot contain 'home' in the path";
                    continue;
                    ;;
                *) 
                    echo "you have entered a valid path";
                    break;
                    ;;
            esac
        fi    
    done    
}

function main() {
    project1_install_dir_path    
}

main;
```

Comment: Just a note, trailing `;` is not necessary if you're using newline to separate commands. If two commands are on the same line, then you do want to use semicolon, as in  `echo foo ; echo bar`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Exactly. It's just a habit of mine because some other languages (Perl, for example) need it. Python, as another example, does _not_ need it and in fact warns you about deprecated or old-fashioned style if you put `;` after a statement. Please feel invited to remove the unnecessary `;` from this post.

Comment: Three general remarks: You are not really using boolian_2, your are asking textually for a confirmation which is not asked for, and finally there are other strings defining a path in my home that would pass your tests (like ~/mydir, or /*/myusername, ...).

Comment: Indeed, @muclux. I just fixed the syntax, not the semantics of the original script.